# Subset data by months in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame of daily precipitation data that runs from Jan-1980 to Dec-2017. I have aggregated monthly averages (as seen in the image). How would I go about examining certain months (E.G. compare all Decembers)?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVmCQ.png)

Comment: Please include reproducible example, sharing code via linked screenshots it's not helpful. Have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1655567) for some guidance for creating good examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your could select the Decembers and draw a plot from this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dd.agg %>%
  # filter all Decembers
  dplyr::filter(mo == "12") %>%
  # change name of last column
  dplyr::rename(precipitation = 3) %>%
  # change year to integer just in case it is char
  dplyr::mutate(yr = as.integer(yr)) %>%
  # order by year just in case it is unorderes
  dplyr::arrange(yr) %>%
  # draw a bar chart
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = yr, y = precipitation)) +
  ggplot2::geom_col()
```